# How to convert arabic character to its base glyph form in Python 3?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, arabic

As a single arabic character can take on multiple glyph forms there are multiple unicode/utf-8 encoding for each form e.g *Aleph*: **`Isolated == ا`** with `utf-8==\xD8\xA7`, **`Final == ـا`** with `utf-8==\xD9\x80\xD8\xA7`, **`Hamza == أ / إ`** with `utf-8==\xD8\xA5 / \xD8\xA3`, **`Maddah == آ`** with `utf-8==\xD8\xA2`, **`Maqsurah == ى`** with `utf-8==\xD9\x89`, where the base form would be the isolated aleph with `utf-8==\xD8\xA7`.

How can I convert an arabic character to its base glyph form in Python 3?

Comment: Note: in theory good Unicode text should not use "glyphs codepoints", but when it is important (e.g. in school books, or reproducing very old text, where the glyph is the important part, not the text) and so probably it should not be converted. But for compatibility with old encodings you may get the different forms (old time with stupider computer, so "pre-rendering" was necessary). See the answers how to to it, or https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/ch09.pdf for details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `unicodedata.normalize` to convert code points to their decomposed form, consisting of a base character and a modifier.  It doesn't work for all cases (particularly Maqsurah), but could help you write a function to determine some base forms:

```
>>> s='ـا' # this character already consisted of the base code point.
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> for c in s:
...     print(f'{c} U+{ord(c):04X} {ud.name(c)}')
...     
ـ U+0640 ARABIC TATWEEL
ا U+0627 ARABIC LETTER ALEF

>>> s = 'أإآ' # These characters have decomposed forms
>>> for c in s:
...     print(f'{c} U+{ord(c):04X} {ud.name(c)}')
...     
أ U+0623 ARABIC LETTER ALEF WITH HAMZA ABOVE
إ U+0625 ARABIC LETTER ALEF WITH HAMZA BELOW
آ U+0622 ARABIC LETTER ALEF WITH MADDA ABOVE
>>> s = ud.normalize('NFD',s)
>>> for c in s:
...     print(f'{c} U+{ord(c):04X} {ud.name(c)}')
...     
ا U+0627 ARABIC LETTER ALEF
ٔ  U+0654 ARABIC HAMZA ABOVE
ا U+0627 ARABIC LETTER ALEF
ٕ  U+0655 ARABIC HAMZA BELOW
ا U+0627 ARABIC LETTER ALEF
ٓ  U+0653 ARABIC MADDAH ABOVE
```